# A rash of ridiculous questions

Tags: discussion

Is it just me or has the site been experiencing a bunch of very very ridiculous questions lately?

[Kill With Voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53849/kill-with-voltage)

[Detect 2 paper overflow](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53845/detect-2-paper-overflow)

Has this always been the case? Anything we can do about it?

Comment: You are going to have people that play a game and because of the game get very interested in something like electricity, I wish people had been a bit less rude when letting the user down, that user might want to be an EE one day because of his fascination with electricity.

Answer (score 4):

There have always been some user posting low-quality questions, or also good questions posed in the wrong way. It's also expectable, since there aren't any restriction for users to post a question, not even registering.

But there's plenty of instruments to sort bad questions out, and that's I think the real peculiarity of the site. The **voting system** allows to put in highlight *good* questions, and the fact alone of getting answers pushes the question up in the home page.

Another instrument, in the hands of more experienced users and moderator, is **closing votes**. These prevent bad questions from being answered, giving time to the poster to improve them by editing.

So the site is equipped to handle bad questions, and there is nothing more to do than to use all the instruments that it gives, since both the voting and closing tools are part of a user-based moderation system.

Comment: "voting system allows to put in highlight popular questions," Small correction. The voting system is for highlighting *good* questions, not *popular* ones. And Popular!=Good most of the times.

Comment: @AshRj you're right, popularity should be a consequence of quality, but unfortunately that's not always the case

Answer (score 1):

There are occasional "algae bloom / red tide" on EE.SE.  A day or so is dominated by various types of low quality questions.  This happens about once or twice a month.

I have access to some of the moderation tools, so I use them.  @clabacchio have already described the process.